# Mac App for auto lowering itunes volume

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am trying to create a menubar app, that sits in the background, reduces iTunes playback volume to 10% if any other app has a sound output. Otherwise, iTunes will be set to 100%. Similar to how iTunes behaves when you get a Facetime call.

I have fairly good idea on controlling iTunes part of things, however, I can't seem to detect if any other app is having a sound output.

Any ideas on where I should be looking to achieve this? If this is even a valid idea?

Cheers!